# How to set auto=repeat on a qaction in a qtoolbar?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to use the autorepeat feature of the QToolButton class.

The problem is that the instances are created automatically when using QToolBar::addAction() and I can't find a way to reach them: QToolBar::widgetForAction() doesn't seem to work in that case (always returns NULL).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be no simple way. The best I found is to use QObject::findChldren :

```
foreach(QToolButton* pButton, pToolBar->findChildren<QToolButton*>()) {

    if (pButton->defaultAction() == pTheActionIWant) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in my case doesn't return NULL, maybe you are doing something different. My code is as follows:

```
QToolButton* button = dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>(
    ui.toolBar->widgetForAction(ui.action));
```

For me it works as intended.... Maybe you aren't casting? This method returns a QWidget* and my compiler issues and error if I don't cast.

FYI, I'm using Visual Studio 2005 with Qt 4.6.

Comment: I'm using Qt 4.5, they may have fixed it since.